# Is it possible to use the Silent Image spell to give the Frightened condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, illusion, fear

I was wondering if it would be possible to use an illusion spell such as *silent image* to try to frighten enemies (by projecting a scary image, for example).

If this were the case, it would be better than a spell that makes the target frightened of you, because you can control the movement by pushing them away from a point that you control, so I feel this might be overpowered.

I don't see anything in the rules against this interpretation, nor do I see anything suggesting that it would be allowed.

**Is it possible to use the *silent image* spell to give the Frightened condition?**
If this is allowed, would the DC for the Wisdom save be my spell save DC?

Comment: As a note, the [frightened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Frightened) condition on its own doesn't force any sort of movement; it only prevents you from willingly moving closer to the source of your fear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### No

People do not make a saving throw against fear when they see a dragon because they see something scary, they do so because the dragon has the *Frightful Presence* feature; something an illusion of a dragon doesn't have. Or, for a more thematic and less mechanical view, it is because a Silent Image doesn't pant like a dragon, doesn't radiate heat like a dragon, doesn't make the ground tremble like a dragon, doesn't have the foundry stink in your nostrils like a dragon, and doesn't remind you in your very genes that you are descended from rodents, you miserable primate!

Spells only do what they say they do. You can certainly come up with clever usages for a spell like Silent Image—like a fake bridge over a chasm or a wall blocking a tunnel etc.—but you can't give it mechanical effects it just doesn't have.

Comment: "you are descended from rodents you miserable primate" is my new favourite dragon-quote

Comment: @AricFowler thank you, I impressed myself with that one.

Comment: Surprised by your own excellence, what a great feeling to have!

Comment: A solid answer (per usual, and the usual +1) but what about someone who was once frightened by a real dragon being scared by the illusory dragon (sort of a PTSD moment)?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Such a mechanic, while certainly possible (I assume),  seems local to the NPC, rather than local to the image of the dragon. While the dragon-image is the stimulus or prompt for the NPC's fear reaction, the image doesn't mechanically *cause* the NPC's fear in the same way an actual dragon causes fear.

Comment: So what I'm hearing is "get a band together that can simulate all the sense input of seeing a dragon via cantrips".

Comment: @KorvinStarmast you can role play "startled" as part of your action to investigate if you like but the OP was specifically trying to force movement through the frightened condition.

Answer (score 7):

### No.

By RAW and RAI, no, it does not, especially in combat. Spells, for sake of balance, do only what their text says they do. There are instances of spells being used in a clever way, like a *fireball* to create a cave-in to trap people, that seem to be outside of their parameters. But those instance have to be taken in consideration by the DM. In case of illusions, they can do so many things that their powers have to be checked by the DM.

### But, yes, it may.

In some cases, some DM may allow not only illusions, but clever usage of the environment, to cause *panic*, particularly outside of combat. The reason why in combat this would be very hard to achieve is because of the *warrior's mindset*. This mindset is the reason why your characters don't freak out and cower in fear in the presence of a giant lizard that spits acid capable of melting rocks, and this can be applied to any NPC. Nevertheless, this *panic* might be transfer to combat and cause a temporary *frightened condition* (DC determined by the DM).

### It is the DM's world.

In the end, the one who call the shots is the DM. If you are the DM, think about the *rule of cool*; if something seems cool and was clever there is no reason to not allow it. As long as it does not break the game, it suits the narrative and allows for some fun moments, why not?